# pool.map in Python 2.7 and Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I have a program written in Python 2.7, which uses pool.map from multiprocessing. Although it runs just fine on Linux, on Windows it does run even run correctly.

From the error output, the problem seems to be on multiprocessing package. I have searched and understood that many people have problems with the multiprocessing package on Windows, since it lacks the "fork()" function.

The code is more or less like the following:

```
results = []
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=thread_count)
    results.extend(pool.map(function, params))
    pool.close()
```

where `thread_count` is the number of threads to be spawn.
Does anyone have any ideas on why pool.map cannot be run correctly on Windows? Any suggestions on how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: What is the error output?

Comment: The error output is the following:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Konstantinos\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main prepare(preparation_data)
    File "C:\Users\Konstantinos\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 495, in prepare '__parents_main__', file, path_name, etc